# Any tools to extract dllImport?

Tags: c#, .net, com, c++-cli

I would like to call some native methods from c#, but writing Dllimports is quite tedious. I am wondering any tool which can assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have http://pinvoke.net, a wiki website dedicated to writing these; though the are for more common functions that are usually a part of Win32.

There is a tool called the [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120). This is capable of creating P/Invoke calls from C source. Very useful if you have the source code. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there has been a lot of development on it recently, but still an excellent (free) tool.

Comment: PIA sounds too good to be true. How well does it actually work?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I came in with pretty low expectations like you. I was surprised. There are some things COM related that it hasn't quite nailed down perfectly. For Win32 it gets it right every time as it has pre-defined most of it in a giant XML file that it just looks up.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html) it should automatically generate PInvoke for you even from DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You must read `PE file format`, you can do that using `WinAPI`, from `C#` you will must call this functions using `Interop` i suggest MSDN and http://pinvoke.net for documentation.